# Java Question about Static

Tags: java, static

I came across this bug in our code today and it took a while to figure. I found it interesting so I decided to share it. Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
public class Test {

    static
    {
      text = "Hello";
    }

    public static String getTest() {
      return text + " World";
    }

    private static String text = null;
}
```

Guess what `Test.getTest();` returns & why?

Comment: It prints "null World", exactly as expected. What bug exactly do you think is in the code?

Comment: @RMT I meant it was a bug in our code, we didn't intend the current outcome :)

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS well that makes more sense

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should print "null world".  Static initializations are done in the order listed.  If you move the declaration higher than the static block you should get "Hello World".

Comment: `The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code.` http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 1):

It returns "null World" The documentation states that static initialization happens in the order it appears in the source code, so if you move your static block down to the bottom, it will return "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

It returns `null World` because the `text` variable is initialized two times, the first time it's "Hello" and the second time it's null.
IF you move your `text` variable declaration before the static init you will get `Hello World`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be "null World".

Answer (score 0):

Java Initializers are defined to execute in the same order they appear in the source code, so your initialization block will run before you assign null to text.

pro tip against such bugs: Make your static variables final, or don't use static variables at all.